# Reading only the request body in a PUT upload

Tags: django, put

I have a Django view which accepts an uploaded file over `PUT`. I've created my own upload handler and am processing the data in chunks like so:

```
handler = MD5ChecksumUploadHandler()
handler.new_file(field_name="file", file_name="unknown",
                 content_type=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/octet-stream'),
                 content_length=int(request.META.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0)))

upload_size = 0

while True:
    # read the request body in chunks
    chunk = request.read(handler.chunk_size)

    if chunk:
        handler.receive_data_chunk(chunk, start=None)
        upload_size += len(chunk)
    else:
        break

# return the MD5ChecksumUploadedFile
return handler.file_complete(upload_size)
```

As I've found out, the `request.read` method starts reading at the beginning of the actual *request* and not the request *body*. This causes my MD5 checksums to fail, which is incidentally good, as I know that something's going wrong.

Is there a way for me to read the actual request body rather than just the raw request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request I was making was a bad one, that's what my problem was:

```
Content-MD5\n: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Check your request if you're having this problem.